Are interrogative pronouns deictic?
From what I've read, deixis happens when some constituent or other can't be interpreted without information about the context of the utterance.  For example ...

First and second person pronouns are deictic, because their referents
change depending on who is talking and who is being addressed.
Demonstrative pronouns are deictic because we can't interpret them
without knowing what is figuratively or literally close to or away
from the speaker at the time of the utterance.

Types of expressions other than pronouns can be deictic too, e.g., "now," "then," "here," and "there."  But I want to focus on pronouns.
Are interrogative pronouns deictic?  Their interpretations seem to me to be dependent on context, but I think I'm missing something.

Some interrogative pronouns are clearly related to deictic forms (that – what; there – where). However, the paradigms are incomplete (e.g. that : what :: this : *whis). This suggests that interrogative pronouns select for certain deictic feature values: in this case, [+distal]. The reason for this may be that it depends on who is speaking whether a question is asked at all. A asks B a question when A lacks information she thinks B has; in this situation, the question is infelicitous when B is speaking to A.

Sorry, this is not correct: that and there can be used deictically but need not. It is correct that deixis has different dimensions like place, time, speaker-hearer etc, but not everything that falls into such categories is therefore deictic. Even then, you have already said that there is a +-distal distinction in the demonstratives that/this, but at the same time no such distinction in the area of question words.

@Alazon my point is precisely that the paradigm is incomplete, and that this can be explained by an analysis in which interrogatives are deictic. The fact that there are no proximal interrogatives therefore does not show that interrogatives are not deictic.

That's logically flawed. You cannot just posit that interrogatives will be deictic (just to explain something) because it's not possible semantically. -- Yes, demonstratives and questions words form "paradigms" but they are not of a unified meaning type; rather they come in pairs because they form question-answer pairs. These have to involve different meaning types. The answer will be definite and therefore can be deictic, but the question cannot be definite, and hence can never be deictic.

@Alazon you only assert things, you don’t make an argument that those claims make for a better analysis. For instance, why would deictics necessarily be definite?

For example: "All personal pronouns are definite. Their referents are always uniquely determined in the context of utterance" (S. Löbner, Understanding Semantics, Routledge 2013, chapter 4 "Meaning and context", p. 64.) -- It's the very definition of definiteness that the referent is "given", deixis is just one way in which it can be given. Adverbs like "now" are analogous to pronouns, they just refer to different sorts of entities.

@Alazon I agree that deixis can provide a way for something to be given/definite, but this does not mean that deixis implies givenness/definiteness.

Then we need a counterexample: a deictic reference to something present in the utterance context that is treated as discourse-new. Do you have something specific in mind? I can't think of such an example. It sounds contradictory.

@Alazon the burden of proof lies on you to substantiate the claim that deixis requires givenness. The Löbner quote above is about definiteness, not deixis, and your argument there only offers support for the weaker claim that deixis can provide givenness.

The Löbner quote is actually about Contexts of Utterance, that's the chapter topic. Deixis does not "require" givennes, it is a kind of givenness. Just like the deictic pronouns "I, you" are intrinsically definite pronouns, as the quote says. -- But if we cannot find out what you would accept as an argument, we'll have to leave this discussion open.

@Alazon and Keelan How about this example. < A: You've got a nasty surprise coming; B: What?; A: This! (and clumps him round the head) > The clump round the head is discourse new and not given, but the this is deictic.

Clever example. But crucially, it uses a definite expression for its deictic reference: "this". What Keelan is looking for would rather be an indefinite that is referential and deictic.  – It is not impossible that a definite expression constitutes the first mention of something in discourse. It must simply be possible to recover the referent, sometimes via inference etc ("accommodation"). The point about indefinite expressions is that they are linguistic devices for signalling that an entity is being presented as a new discourse referent. "A new entity in the world" is a different issue.

@Alazon What you wrote, though was: "Deixis does not "require" givenness, it is a kind of givenness." In the clump round the head example, the word this is does not represent something already 'given' in that sense.

deixis requires referentiality, not givenness. The referent can be real in the physical world, or abstract and only in language. Who came yesterday? "who" clearly is "pointing" at a person. Right?

(answer reorganised  Oct 16)
Interrogative pronouns are not deictic, because they are not even referential. Deixis is a subtype of reference, namely reference to something given in the utterance situation. Note that deixis does not merely mean that the utterance context restricts the meaning of an expression (like: which dog it is when you say "the dog"); we are specifically dealing with a pointing gesture towards a referent that is given by the utterance situation.
It appears that "what" is formally related to "that" and "that" can be used deictically. But that doesnt lead to a deictic function of "what", because it's precisely the "wh"-part that distinguishes question words from demonstratives. So in a way, "that" would be seen as referential because of the "th-" part, not because of the "-at" part that it has in common with "what".
"There" can be deictic because it can symbolise a pointing gesture to a place in the utterance situation, but it can also be non-deictic if it refers back to something that has been mentioned before (anaphoric use), and this is typical of a definite expression. The wh-counterpart "where" is essentially an indefinite, and indefinites cannot be anaphoric. So, the word "somewhere" (the indefinite variant not forming questions) does the contrary of referring back to a place mentioned before, for it serves to introduce a new place into the discourse. Deixis, however, is about things that are already "given".
Question formation is built on the semantics of an indefinite pronoun. The question operator creates a set of alternative propositions. For example, "What did he buy" denotes a set of propositions that all have the form "There is an x: he bought x". The straightforward way of answering this is to provide the specific x that yields a true proposition. There is no connection to deixis.
It has been widely observed that wh-words in constituent questions are grammatically indefinites, take e.g.:

Manfred Krifka: Questions. In Claudia Maienborn, Klaus von Heusinger, Paul Portner (eds.): Semantics: An International Handbook of Natural Language Meaning. Walter de Gruyter, Berlin 2011. Vol 2, chapter 66.
See esp. a passage from p. 1771:


Interrogative pronouns like when and where can be decomposed into two parts: one expressing interrogativity (wh-), the other expressing the type or sort of entities that are asked (e.g., -en for time, which also occurs in th-en; -ere for place, which also occurs in th-ere). In most languages, this combination appears to be at least partially transparent, and we find completely transparent systems in Pidgin and Creole languages (cf. Muysken & Smith 1990).
In many languages, interrogative pro-forms are related to indefinite pro-forms, as in English how and somehow, or German wer and irgendwer (cf. Haspelmath 1997).

From p. 1772:

The similarity between indefinite and interrogative pronouns is well-motivated at an intuitive level: these two forms have in common that semantic information is left unspecified. How can this intuition be captured by the different frameworks of question representations? As for the proposition set representation, notice that it can be rendered in a format in which the wh-constituent is represented by an existential indefinite:
(130) who read ‘War and Peace’
λp∃x[person(x) ∧ p=λi[readi(w&p)(x)]]


Some interrogative pronouns in some languages are overtly marked with definiteness markers (e.g., Amharic የቱ yät-u ‘which’, whose expected base form የት yät is not used), which does not seem particularly compatible with the notion that interrogatives specifically combine indefinite pronouns with question operators.

I agree that it's not clear from the answer why interrogatives should be thought of as related to indefinites.

I dont understand the argument from Amharic.  But note that we need a semantic argument, morphology may have lots of motivations and explanations and can also be accidental. The same flaw as in  Keelan's comment above. –"Which" would mean "which one of them" Here, "one" is visibly an indefinite, i.e. you have to choose one or another from a group. A question word cannot be definite, because definite means you already know which one it is. Then you cannot formulate a question.

Ah, one example that I would understand is found in German: In German you can ask for ordinal numbers, though it's impossible in English: "He celebrates his 50th birthday" - question in German: "Den wievielten Geburtstag feiert er?" (the how-many-eth birthday does he celebrate). But note that the question word is actually "wie" (how), it's just embeded in a construction that carries a definite. I wonder why, but perhaps it's definite because it's unique: there can only be 1 birthday for every number. - So all this doesn't lead to counterarguments. And the indefinite analysis isn't my invention

You write that where is indefinite and therefore cannot be anaphoric. What do you make of wh relativizers?

It would be good if you turn this into a question of its own because relative clauses are an intricate topic. Relative and interrogative pronouns do not work the same, and we were talking about interrogatives, and that was what I had in mind. So, good question. The textbook analysis is that relative clauses combine with nouns just in the same way as adjectives do, that's predication, not anaphora. But certain detached relative clauses do look anaphoric. It boils down to the question why wh-words may appear as relativisers. That's not something you find in the literatur about question semantics

I added a restriction to questions in the literature section of my answer. Good point, Keelan

All of this has a big "textbook" and "that's how we've always done it" feel, and I'm sorry, but I'm missing explanations why these would be the preferred analyses. I think "relative and interrogative pronouns do not work the same" should not be an excuse not to look at parallels: there is a cross-linguistically recurring syncretism there, which requires an explanation, even if there are also differences between the two. In my view, deictic/spatial features can be of use in explaining these parallels, even if that is not something you'd find in textbooks.

In a sense, yes, you missed the explanations. I am citing textbooks to show that I am not making stuff up, otherwise they show there's a coherent argument. – Note that (in contrast to questions) w-pronouns are not obligatory to build relative clauses; there are lots of other forms of relative clauses. And at least in German you see that w- and d-pronouns are suddenly exchangeable in the function of relativisers, while they form contrast sets if the w-pronoun is interrogative. So relativisers surely are different.

Yes, also in relativizers only the distal form is available. This can be explained in the same way, however, since relativizers are always coreferential with another item and therefore always discourse-old.

"The question operator creates a set of alternative propositions. For example, "What did he buy" denotes a set of propositions that all have the form "There is an x: he bought x". Answering this means to provide the specific x that yields a true proposition." <-- No, this is often wheeled out, but it is wrong, imo. A completely fine answer to this question is "He did not buy anything".

This overlooks that the quotation describes the kind of semantic object that a questions represents, – it's not about the ways in which a reaction to a question may qualify as an answer.

@Keelan: An anaphoric function of a relativiser mostly concerns the case of "which". The form "which" is not related to a proximal/distal distinction like this/that. -- The relativiser "what"(which does look like "that") mostly occurs in free relatives where there is no nominal antecedent at all ("I am sceptical of what he says"). -- For the case of relative "where" note examples like "Here, where everything is better" This would be contradictory if "where" were to carry a distal meaning like "there". (Moreover, modification is not anaphora).

In Here, where everything is better, the comparative introduces a different origo from which here is distal. I think there usually (always?) is a contextually salient origo in this way.

@Araucaria: Now I notice that I had a description of answers in my text that was too narrow, I  have revised it to meet your objection.

@Keelan: Your answer is confusing. "Here" and "where" make reference to the very same place, because "where" is a relative modifier attached to "here". And "here" is not distal. The meaning is "Here, where everything is better (than in that other place)" (and we are here).

The origo in the main clause is different from the origo in the relative clause. In the main clause, the origo is the Speaker's origo. In the relative clause, the origo is shifted to the contextually salient worse place. This is why here and where refer to the same place, but here is proximal, and where is distal. This is even the case for, say, Here, where I am. Contextually this implies a different origo from where we are comparing, i.e. something like (and not) where you are.
